# check if data exists in temp table, and then insert into real table

Tags: database

I have a list of over 1000 phone numbers in a temp table that need to be checked whether they exist in 2 real tables of each database roughly 25 Dbs.

- In other words, I have 25 DBs, each database has 2 tables ('subscribed' and 'unsubscribed'). What I need to accomplish is checking each of these 1000 numbers from my temp table with a 'phonenumber' column in 'subscribed' table.
- If a match is found, I need to add that phone number to 'unsubscribed' table. Which would be the fastest route using cursors or sth else ? 
  thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest adding what kind of database you are using... Also, try to use some line breaks to make your question more readable.

Comment: it's a sql server database 2008. T-sql syntax. thanks

Comment: my temp table has one column named phonenumbers where 1000 phone numbers are listed. Each of the tables(named subscribed and unsubscribed) has a column named phonenumbers. e.x after the first phone number from the temp-table is checked against 'subscibed' table in one of the DBs and a match is found, that number is added into unsubscribed table of the same DB.